# How to filter between datetime range in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which I want to filter based on `day` range and set the `month` column base on that condition.

In a simple term, any day between day(1-5), subtract 1 from `month` otherwise set `month = month`

```
  day   month
0   1   6
1   4   6
2   4   6
3   4   6
4   4   6
5   4   6
6   6   6
7   8   6
8   12  6
9   12  6


if all(df[df['day'].between(1, 5)]):
    
    df.month = df.month - 1
    
else:
    df.month = df.month
```

Expected output

```
  day   month
0   1   5
1   4   5
2   4   5
3   4   5
4   4   5
5   5   5
6   6   6
7   8   6
8   12  6
9   12  6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Boolean indexing on the `'day'` column and subtract 1 from the relevant part of the `'month'` column:

```
df.loc[df.day<6, 'month'] -= 1
```